# can't install pip on win10, syntax error, PATH VARIABLE

Tags: python, syntax, path, pip

I've tried researching installing pip on my win10 machine. I 2 version of python installed, 2.7 and 3.6. I'd like to use 3.6 with 'oemof' package. I have downloaded the 'pip' module and it's installed, however when I try to run pip 
(from the IDLE) I always get a syntax error. I can import the pip,(in IDLE) but the error, "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" always pops up.
Reading the docs, it says you need to run pip from the command line, however, I can't do that because, I think, the PATH variable may be wrong. I have win2.7 installed on my C:\Python27. How can I install python36 in the C: drive directly? As of now it's on my LOCAL profile, I think that may be the problem.

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: You can type path=C;\Python27 to set the temporary path and execute pip and see the download options for Python3.6 https://www.python.org/

Comment: Both 2.7 and 3.6 are distributes with pip. It should not need to be installed separately.

Answer (score 1):

Pip have to be used from the command prompt either like this:

```
\> pip3 install library
```

Or if the path isn't set properly, like this:

```
\> py -3 -m pip install library
```

Or if that still does not work as that the py command somehow wasn't installed with the installation, do it like this:

```
\> c:\path\to\python36\python.exe -m pip install library
```

All of the above commands should be ran from the cmd. Alternatively, if you seriously want to run pip from IDLE, you can do this:

```
import pip
pip.main(['install', 'library'])
```